# ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.Use a.any() or a.all(). While using dataset_from_directory

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tf.data.dataset

Want to convert images in directory to tensors in tf.dataset.Dataset format, so =>
[tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/image_dataset_from_directory): *Generates a tf.data.Dataset from image files in a directory*

> labels:    Either "inferred" (labels are generated from the directory structure), None (no labels), ***or a list/tuple of integer labels of the same size as the number of image files found in the directory***. Labels should be sorted according to the alphanumeric order of the image file paths (obtained via os.walk(directory) in Python). [From docs]

First I encoded the labels

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
encoder = LabelEncoder()
y_train = encoder.fit_transform(list(y_train["breed"]))
```

then while using

```py
train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  TRAIN_IMG_PATH,
  labels=y_train,
  label_mode='int',
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size
)
```

got error

```py
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/utils/image_dataset.py:163: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  if labels not in ("inferred", None):

...

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: `y_train["breed"]` what is like? int?

Comment: It is a pandas Series.

Comment: I mean data type. It should be matched with `label_mode`

Comment: **'int': means that the labels are encoded as integers (e.g. for sparse_categorical_crossentropy loss).**
from docs